# hive ORDER BY on String

Tags: sql, hive

```
select
concat('\"',NVL(NVL(A.col1),''),'\"|',
'\"',NVL(col2,''),'\"|',
'\"',NVL(case when 
length(trim(col3))>0 then SHIP
else Col7 end,''),'\"|',
'\"',NVL(col4,''),'\"|') 
as `Mycol1,Mycol2,Mycol4,Mycol5' from TableA A left outer join TableB B 
on A.Col5 = B.Col5 ;
```

On this result how can I do an ORDER BY on COL3?

Comment: What's wrong with `ORDER BY col3` ?

Comment: Since its results as a single concatenated value,sort by on col3 is not working .

Comment: Do you have to only return that result ? Can you select `col3` also ?

Comment: can you add the error that you are getting and table definitions would be useful as well

Comment: Do we have `NVL` in hive?

Comment: We ca't select col3.We need the result as the same(concatenated value).

Comment: We are not getting any error.But order by is not working

Comment: We have NVL in Hive

Answer (score 0):

Nest the result ordered by `col3` and then select the required columns outside.

```
SELECT Mycol1
    ,Mycol2
    ,Mycol4
    ,Mycol5
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT (
            '\"'
            ,NVL(NVL(A.col1), '')
            ,'\"|'
            ,'\"'
            ,NVL(col2, '')
            ,'\"|'
            ,'\"'
            ,NVL(CASE 
                    WHEN length(trim(col3)) > 0
                        THEN SHIP
                    ELSE Col7
                    END, '')
            ,'\"|'
            ,'\"'
            ,NVL(col4, '')
            ,'\"|'
            ) AS Mycol1
        ,Mycol2
        ,Mycol4
        ,Mycol5
        ,col3
    FROM TableA A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.Col5 = B.Col5
    ORDER BY col3
    ) t;
```